# How would I create smarter HTTP links in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have lots of links that look like:

```
https://domain.com/en/res/main/r1/sm-e/spec/1/1#q=1-1-1
```

I want to be able to enter a string like:

```
A-1-1
```

and be able to create a correct link like:

```
[[https://domain.com/en/res/main/r1/sm-e/spec/1/1#q=1-1-1][A-1-1]]
```

In the past, I was able to find help for links to pdf documents. But this is more complex, but I would love to hear your suggestions.

## Can I have a bonus answer?

How do I pass multiple parameters to my abbreviations? Can the following be a clue? where I can find examples?

```
(org-link-set-parameter "type" :complete #'some-completion-function)
```

Comment: `C-h i g (org)Link Abbreviations RET` should help.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr:

```
#+LINK: jira  https://jira.mycompany.com/browse/%s
[[jira:TASK-1234][TASK-1234: label]]
```

will create the links you desire.

As NickD mentions, find ["Link Abbreviations" in the org manual.](https://orgmode.org/manual/Link-Abbreviations.html#Link-Abbreviations), also via `C-h i g (org)Link Abbreviations <RET>`

Comment: The first step is done. Now, how do I translate ticket1234 into TASK-1234?

Comment: Something link `M-x query-replace-regexp <RET> \(ticket\([0-9]+\)\) <RET> [[jira:TASK-\2]] <RET>` should work.